# How to query all the columns which contain non-NUll element in a table?

Tags: dolphindb

Take an example, I create a table as follows:

```py
x1 = 1 NULL 2 NULL NULL
x2 = 1 NULL NULL 3 4
x3 = 3 NULL 3 4 5
x4 = take(double(NULL), 5)
t = table(x1 ,x2 ,x3, x4)
```

I want to remove the columns in which the element are all NULL, how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the following feature by using the “sqlCol” function to generate meta code:

1. Generate meta code which will remove all NULL columns
2. Execute the metacode

The example code is as below:

```py
sql(select=sqlCol(t.schema().colDefs.name[each(isValid, t.values()).sum()!=0]), from=t).eval()
```

The result table is:

| x1 | x2 | x3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
|  |  |  |
| 2 |  | 3 |
|  | 3 | 4 |
|  | 4 | 5 |